# SQL select two count from one table

Tags: sql

I have a table with columns:
COURSE_ID (int)
SKILL_ID (int)

One course could have many skills, for example the table could contain values:

| COURSE_ID | SKILL_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |

The result should show count of courses and count of skills they have.
For example for the table above the result should be:

1 = 1 (course 3 has 1 skill)  (count course with 1 skill = 1)

2 = 2 (course 1 and 4 have 2 skills) (count course with 2 skill = 2)

3 = 1 (course 2 has 3 skills) (count course with 3 skill = 1)

Could anybody help with this query?

And one more question. I tried to execute this query and I am expecting one number with count of courses with 6 skills, but I got many records (in fact - rows count = expected result, value in rows = 6), can't understand why, could anybody explain?

```
select count(table.course_id) from Table table
GROUP BY table.course_id
HAVING COUNT(table.skill_id) = 6
```

Comment: What database do you use ? Please tag it.

Comment: "2 = 2 (course 2 and 4 have 2 skills)" I believe you wanted to say : 2 = 2 (course 1 and 4 have 2 skills)

Comment: Please explain every number in your expected result : 3 = 1 (course 2 has 3 skills)

Comment: Numbers were corrected, you are right about course with 2 skills.

Comment: 3 = 1 (course 2 has 3 skills)
Only one course has 3 skills

Comment: Hi @ysevk and the database is ? Oracle ? SQLServer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're expecting as a result but I *think* this is what you're after

```
select Skill, Count(*) courseCount
from (
    select course_id, Count(distinct SKILL_ID) Skill
    from t
    group by COURSE_ID
)s
group by Skill;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e575d1efd5ee5d30d9d93363b72d357e)

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select table.course_id, count(table.skill_id)
from table_name table
GROUP BY table.course_id
```

And your query should be

```
select table.course_id, count(table.skill_id)
from table_name table
GROUP BY table.course_id
HAVING COUNT(table.skill_id) = 6
```